# How to get current user id in spring?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have a spring boot app with spring security:

```
<spring-security-oauth2.version>2.2.1.RELEASE</spring-security-oauth2.version>
<spring-security-jwt.version>1.0.9.RELEASE</spring-security-jwt.version>
```

and i've the folowwing user entity:

```
`@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
@NotNull
private String name;
@NotNull
private String email;
@NotNull
private String pass;
```

//permission
//gets and sets
`

I want to get the user ID logged in, for this I have tried as follows:

```
@GetMapping("/userId")
@ResponseBody
public String currentUserName(Authentication authentication) {
    return authentication.getName();
}
```

But i only get the user name. If someone can help me I would appreciate it.

Comment: Depending on your setup, you may be able to `((UserEntity) authentication.getPrincipal()).getId()`. Also, take a look at `@AuthenticationPrincipal` in the ref doc: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#mvc-authentication-principal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query the database to get the id. If you are using Spring Data, create a method in repository:

```
User findByName(String name);
```

And use it:

```
Long id = userRepository.findByName(authentication.getName()).getId();
```

Comment: this way it is possible to get there! the problem is if you have two users with the same name.

Comment: Make the column name unique or use email to differentiate between users.

Answer (score 0):

In your entity class

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
```

this means , your id is your private key and it is going to be generated in your database. You will save an entity and you will get the entity with your id.

What i recommend is use JpaRepository. You need to add a dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

And you want to create a Repository interface.

```
public interface RepositoryName extends JpaRepository<Entity, String> {}
```

In your controller.class ; inject your service and go to its methods. Inject repository in your service.

In your service method you can use

```
Entiy entity = repository.findById(id);
```

and its good to go.

Comment: I am using JPA. I don't want to find users by ID (like JPA query).
In order to have access to the app, it is necessary to login, I want to know what is the ID of the logged user.

Comment: Okay. In order to user to log in, user has to be in your database. Is user's name unique? It has to be cuz user will log in with it. Then you can access userId with user name. If this is not what you want, i will go an write simular code to solve the problem.